# extract image url using javascript from a HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

i have the source of a html section saved as a string :

```
var str= '<div class="quizdisplay themestylename theme_db_primarykey">
        <h1>What Power Would Suit You Best</h1>
        <p class="inline_byline"">Created by <a class="url fn" href="/user/xQUANTUMNxNOVAx/profile">xQUANTUMNxNOVAx</a></p>

        <div class="metacrumb">

                  <dl>

                    <dt>Tagged:</dt>

                      <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag" href="/tags/dark" title="dark">dark</a></dd>, <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag"
 href="/tags/personality" title="personality">personality</a></dd>,
 <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag" href="/tags/air"
 title="air">air</a></dd>, <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag"
 href="/tags/power" title="power">power</a></dd>, <dd><a class="tag"
 rel="tag" href="/tags/fire" title="fire">fire</a></dd>, <dd><a
 class="tag" rel="tag" href="/tags/water" title="water">water</a></dd>,
 <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag" href="/tags/energy"
 title="energy">energy</a></dd>, <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag"
 href="/tags/earth" title="earth">earth</a></dd>, <dd><a class="tag"
 rel="tag" href="/tags/lightning" title="lightning">lightning</a></dd>,
 <dd><a class="tag" rel="tag" href="/tags/telekinesis"
 title="telekinesis">telekinesis</a></dd>

                   </dl>

                </div>

        <div id="itemresults" class="quidget">
            <p>
                5493 other people got this result!
                That's 34%
            </p>
                        <a class="button viewallresults">View all results</a>
                            <a href="/quizzes" class="button" style="line-height:23px;width:150px;">Take another quiz!</a>

        </div>

        <h3 class="aquestion">Water/Ice.</h3>

                <img src="/user_images/X/XQ/XQU/XQUANTUMNXNOVAX/1346304322_6798_full.jpeg"
 alt="result image" />

        <p>You go with the flow, following the motions of the world around you. You're calming and relaxing but have an aggressive side to
 you when necessary. You can be in tune with people easily, or can be
 completely cold hearted. People typically love you, and need you the
 most.</p>

 </div>';
```

how do i extract the image url from this string using javascript ?

Comment: please remove all the `>` from you code and format properly

Comment: that's not a string, that's a syntax error

Comment: i have saved the whole HTML as a string .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### jquery

```
var srcArray = [];
$(str).find('img').each(function(){
   src = $(this).attr('src');
   srcArray.push(src);
});
```

Or you can use Regex:

```
var regex = /(?<=<img src=").*?(?=")/gm;
src = regex.match(str);
alert(src);
```

examle on [this link](http://regexr.com?321t3).

Comment: i need a solution without any library .

Answer (score 0):

Since it's HTML. You could insert the whole lot into the DOM (hidden) and use jQuery to grab the image url out, it's a bit hacky, but probably the easiest way.

You could also use a regular expression to search for the image tag and grab the url out of it.